# Why is get-in slower than threading through gets?

Tags: clojure

I came across this while tuning some performance sensitive code:

```
user> (use 'criterium.core)
nil
user> (def n (into {} (for [i (range 20000) :let [k (keyword (str i))]] [k {k k}])))
#'user/n
user> (quick-bench (-> n :1 :1))
WARNING: Final GC required 32.5115186521176 % of runtime
Evaluation count : 15509754 in 6 samples of 2584959 calls.
Execution time mean : 36.256135 ns
Execution time std-deviation : 1.076403 ns
Execution time lower quantile : 35.120871 ns ( 2.5%)
Execution time upper quantile : 37.470993 ns (97.5%)
               Overhead used : 1.755171 ns
nil
user> (quick-bench (get-in n [:1 :1]))
WARNING: Final GC required 33.11057826481865 % of runtime
Evaluation count : 7681728 in 6 samples of 1280288 calls.
Execution time mean : 81.023429 ns
Execution time std-deviation : 3.244516 ns
Execution time lower quantile : 78.220643 ns ( 2.5%)
Execution time upper quantile : 85.906898 ns (97.5%)
               Overhead used : 1.755171 ns
nil
```

It's unintuitive to me that `get-in` is more than twice as slow as threading through `get`s here as `get-in` seems to be defined as the better abstraction for this sort of thing.

Does anyone have any insight into why this is the case (both technically and philosophically)?

Comment: If you look at the source for those two functions, you can see there's some recursion going on in [`get-in`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5882) that allows it to comb through nested structures.  I would guess that's the source of the extra overhead.

Comment: I can only guess that get-in is a more "general purpose" function, and has more overhead.  On my computer it is not quite so bad, at 31 ns vs 57 ns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nested maps are very commonly used in Clojure programs. This is a good thing. But there can be occasions where nested map operations such as `assoc-in` and `get-in` may be improved by unrolling. `(get :a (get :b (get :c (get :d m)))` is not the same thing as `(get-in m [:d :c :b :a])` in terms of the byte code produced. The byte code of the later results in worse execution time.

Note that Clojure has some pending patches http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1656 related to this.

Comment: I don't think recursive function calls are the problem, so much as the many vectors that need to be allocated.